# Shell script - why passing '-n' to a function does not work

Tags: shell, sh

I have a function in my shell script that takes options. It works fine, until I try to pass '-n' option, then the function cannot read the arg.

```bash
func ()
{
for arg in "$@"
do
echo $arg
done
}

func -p #works
func -e #works
func -n #doesn't work, func cannot read arg
```

Anyone has an idea of why this is happening?

Tried: passing multiple options to the function, they all work, except '-n'.
Expect: read '-n' as an argument in my function.

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass the arguments to `echo` make them be considered `echo`'s switches and since `-n` is a valid switch (BTW `-e` is also valid switch on my `echo` you would be lucky just with `-p` here). is not being echoed. If you want to print them using echo you can try adding `--` to signal end of arguments, so `$arg` won't be interpreted as such (`echo -- $arg`) but that also may depend on the shell you are using.

EDIT: as support for `--` is not default, you may want to replace `echo` with `printf`:

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${arg}"
```

Comment: Using `--` doesn’t work on my default macOS bash (`echo -- $arg` prints `-- -n`).

Comment: `echo -- $arg` does not work. using `printf` solved the issue.

Comment: I'm running `#!/bin/sh` script from a Debian system.

Comment: side note: `/bin/sh` is usually symlink to `bash`, `dash` or any other more modern shell than `sh`.

Comment: Yes, just checked it's a symlink to `dash` on Debian bookworm. Thanks for the answer (do not have enough reputation to cast a vote...).

Comment: "More modern" is not entirely accurate. Ideally `/bin/sh` should be a POSIX `sh` but in practice this is only more or less true. Which shell exactly tries to implement this is, by definition, an implementation detail; but you should not try to use non-POSIX features in portable `sh` scripts. If it's for your local use only, of course, you can cut corners if you know exactly how your `/bin/sh` deviates from POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

`-n` might be interpreted as an option for the `echo` command. To avoid this, [use `printf` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451742/4652564):

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$arg"
```